# ZyBooks name permutation python

Tags: python, permutation

I have a problem when learning the zyBooks about Python. 7.4 LAB asks me to write a program about all permutations of names. The details are shown below.

[image]

Here is my code but I do not know why there is no output. Could you please help me with it? Really appreciate it.

```
def all_permutations(permList, nameList):
    # TODO: Implement method to create and output all permutations of the list of names.
    import itertools
    permList = list(itertools.permutations(nameList))
    return permList

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    nameList = input().split(' ')
    permList = []
    all_permutations(permList, nameList)
```

Comment: Your program prints nothing because it contains no print statements.

Comment: I assume they intend for you to do `permList.extend(itertools.permutations(nameList))`. Otherwise why include permList as a parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:
`

```
def all_permutations(permList, nameList):
    # TODO: Implement method to create and output all permutations of the list of names.
    import itertools
    permList = list(itertools.permutations(nameList))
    return permList

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    nameList = input().split(' ')
    permList = all_permutations([], nameList)
    for perm in permList:
        print(', '.join(perm))
```

`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).